# iPhone SDK 3.0 in-app email - changing navigation bar tint color

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

My App uses the iPhone SDK 3.0's new in-app email feature.

I want to change the tint color of the email UI to black and make it translucent.

I tried the following code,

```
/*
picker.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
picker.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES ;
*/
```

But it's changing the color of the view that creates,

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

the compose window, rather than the compose window itself.

Is this atleast possible? Or should we stick to Apple provided blue itself???

Answer (score 5):

Since the MFMailComposeViewController is a subclass of UINavigationController, simply do this:

```
[[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The [iPhone Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/SpecialViews/SpecialViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH10-SW1) do not forbid to use custom colors but recommends the standard colors (blue and black).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Just add a objective-c category in the UINavigationBar class overriding the drawInRect Method.
This way you can do want.

The disadvantage, all your navigation bars will change :)

Comment: Not sure your app will be approved if you do this.

Comment: This is no problem with Apple. This is exactly what I've done in my app (well, actually, a subclass of UINavigationBar), and it was approved by Apple (official Dave Matthews Band app). There's nothing wrong with intercepting drawInRect: to achieve a custom UINavigationBar look.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code....

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailComposeView.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

[[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

....makes the Cancel and Send buttons black too. They are not blue and do not change color when pressed.